# How to make Word wrap in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView, and I would like to make the text word wrap.

Here is my code:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (component == 0) {
    UILabel *lView = (UILabel *)view;

    if (!tView) {
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [tView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
        tView.numberOfLines = [categorie count];
    }
    tView.text = [categorie objectAtIndex:row];
    return tView;
    }
    else {
        UILabel *lView = (UILabel *)view;

        if (!sView) {
            sView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            [sView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
            sView.numberOfLines = [subCat count];
        }
        sView.text = [subCat objectAtIndex:row];
        return sView;
    }
}
```

I tried setting sView.numberOfLines = 0; (which is how you would normally set a UILabel to word wrap, or have more than 1 line) but that didn't work.

Comment: off topic, but on topic: https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide#naming more descriptive variables please :D

Comment: All vars are just arrays

Comment: it's not that this code snippet is difficult to understand, it's that you should consider what I have suggested as best practices for writing your code. it definitely helps out in the long run getting used to something like this

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what happens in your code, for example let's imaging, that `subCat` array contains two string objects: "one", "two"

```
// You try to reuse label for picker
UILabel *sView = (UILabel *)view;
if (!sView) {
    // if this view doesn't exists, you create new label
    sView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [sView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    // And once set numberOfLines to value 2 in our case
    sView.numberOfLines = [subCat count];
}
// And here you set text to "one" or "two" value from array
// I don't understand where you set multiline text value?
sView.text = [subCat objectAtIndex:row];
return sView;
```

You need something like this:

```
sView.text = [subCat componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: I di componentsJoinedByString:@"\n", and what it did was copied the first one for all the other ones. For example, if the first one was "one", it showed "one" in place for all the other rows

Comment: what value you return in `- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component` delegate function? Maybe you return not enough height and label so small, so can't display more than 1 string?

Comment: What do you mean? I set delegate to self, and I did not set a height.

Comment: UIPickerViewDelegate have optional function `rowHeightForComponent`, where you can return height for each picker cell